# Problem adding control using AddAt method [ASP.NET]

Tags: asp.net, controls

On my page I have the following Image control.

```
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="~/images/icons/returnarrow.gif" runat="server" />
```

Then on Page_Load I am doing the following.

```
    Image1.Controls.AddAt(1, new LiteralControl("ChildControl2"));
```

So what this should do (theoretically) is add a new LiteralControl next to the image. But it doesn't. However, If I change the index to 0 and the Image to a GridView control it works.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't modify the Controls collection. Use a [PlaceHolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.placeholder_properties%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: Using a placeholder is a solution but ideally I want to place it next  to the image.

Comment: Then just place a placeholder right after the image. Since the placeholder itself won't produce any markup at all, your control will be rendered right next to image.

Comment: That is a possible solution. I think i'll wait to see if anyone else comes up with something.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so `Image1.Controls.AddAt` will add any control next to Image control because `Image1.Controls` is a collection of child controls of `Image1`, may be `this.Controls.AddAt` will work

Comment: So you don't think it works with Images? I am trying to get my head around why. It's still a .net control like GridView.

Comment: yes because Image control is not itself a container but it has controls property because the base class it's derived from has.

Answer (score 1):

You should be trying to embed another control in an image. Use a PlaceHolder as the parent container, and add the Image and Literal to the PlaceHolder.